# Empty result list for Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using google places api for retrieving info about cafes in different cities.
But sometimes it returns empty results even if there should be items. 
How I search for cafes in Gudauta:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=<key>&location=43.27,40.27&radius=500&types=cafe
```

Also there is no places even on simple maps but I sure they should be there.

[image]

How it looks like in Foursquare:

[image]

The kind of request works fine for huge cities like Vienna or Moscow but fails for small and middle ones.

Is it google bug/lack of data or I do something wrong?

Comment: Your request coordinates (43.27,40.27), are pretty far away from the location of your picture (Gudauta is at (43.1023643, 40.618282), a 41.7 km drive from (43.27,40.27)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. google may only return results based on their data, foursquare may have other data, so you can't compare them
2. the location in your request is placed in a disputed region(abchasia), google usually will not provide data for such regions at all to avoid conflicts

Comment: Genius! A programming answer that can only be answered with some political knowledge...